# How can I find a digit after string with pattern?

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to get the last return code from an SSH shell in linux.
I'm using the command:`echo &?` to get it.
I've written following code but it's not working:

```
int last_len = 0;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("echo $?\r\n[0-9]");
while(in.available() > 0 ) {
    last_len = in.read(buffer);
    String str = new String(buffer, 0, last_len);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    if(m.find()) {
        return Integer.parseInt(m.group().substring(9));
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `$`, `?` in the regex inorder to match the literal form of those characters since `?`, `$` are considered as special chars in regex.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("echo \\$\\?\\r?\\n([0-9])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if(m.find()) {
System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

or

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("echo\\s+\\$\\?[\\r\\n]+([0-9])");
```

Comment: ya, ...`\r` called carriage return and `\n` newline char

Comment: so why you replaced it whit \\r?\\n ?

Comment: both would work. and also you don't need substring method for extracting the number.